# How to select a random document in MongoDB and find 5 next/preceding documents?

Tags: mongodb, random

I have a database with Facebook messages and I want to find a random message and also get the 5 next and the 5 preceding messages. Every document has the following template:

```
_id: ObjectId("5ea27f2d13d10327b2c55bdd")
author : "William"
content : "Hi everybody"
timestamp : 1587502921452
type : "Generic"
```

They all have the timestamp so it would be possible to sort them by timestamp.

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: I tried add a index from 1 to 186093 to every document and I find the the document using
``nb = random.randint(5, len(self.messages.count())-5)`` and something like```self.messages.find({'msg_nb': {'$ge':nb-5, '$le':nb+5}})```.
It works but it just doesn't seem like the easiest path

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`$sample`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/#pipe._S_sample) operator with `size` property to randomly pick `size` number of document(s).

```
var pipeline = [
    {
        $sample: {
            size: 1
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            content: 1
        }
    }
];
db.collection.aggregate(pipeline);
```

Comment: the result does not give consecutive messages, using size=10, it only gives 10 random document through the whole db

Answer (score 0):

- Use $sample to get a random message
- Use find with $gt sorted by timestamp to get 5 newer messages
- Use find with $lt sorted by timestamp in the other direction to get 5 older messages